# React update function from child using context

Tags: reactjs

How can i update a function from a child using context??

The context

```
import React from 'react';

const Fin_states = React.createContext({

title: "title_title"    
});

export default Fin_states;
```

This is the main page , the aim is update function_() using set_function_(see the states const [function_,set_function_] ) , but doing it using the context in the List_of_list child.

```
import React , { useState ,useContext} from 'react';
import Input_list_panel from './Input_list_panel'
import Fin_states from './Financial_instrument_states'

export default function FinancialInstruments() {
//Attribs
const context =  useContext(Fin_states);

const [value, set_value] = useState({title:"initial_title"})
const [function_, set_function_] = useState(() => (data) => console.log(data))


// set_function_ is going to be represented by update_function in the context provider.
return (  
  <>
   <Fin_states.Provider value={{ data:value, update_value:set_value,update_function:set_function_}}>

        <Input_list_panel/>

   </Fin_states.Provider>

        <button onClick={()=>function_("data")}>

          Add item in child from parent
        

        </button>

    </>
   );
 }
```

This is the file where the function is going to be modified using useEffect in this line  context.update_function(()=>updated_function)

```
import React , { useState , useEffect, forwardRef ,useRef,useImperativeHandle, useContext } from 'react';

import Fin_states from './Financial_instrument_states'


export default function List_of_list(props) {

const [list_of_list,set_list_of_list]= useState(["data_1","data_2"]);

const context =  useContext(Fin_states);

const updated_function=(data)=>{

    var new_item=[...list_of_list];
    
    new_item.push(data)

    set_list_of_list(new_item);

    console.log(list_of_list)

}

useEffect(() => {
    
    /*update_function represents at set_function_ to modify function_() state , see the context 
    provider in the parent FinancialInstruments*/

    context.update_function(()=>updated_function)

}, [])

return (
<>
    <Fin_states.Consumer>
        {
            (context)=>{

                return(
                    <>
                        <button onClick={
                            ()=>{
                                updated_function("data")
                            }
                        }>
                            Add item in child
                        </button>
                    </>
                )
            }
        }
    </Fin_states.Consumer>
 </>

 );
}
```

The problem is that when the state of function_() is updated in the main page (FinancialInstruments functional component) it does not use the same context than updated_function() in List_of_list.

How can i have the same result that i have in List_of_list  using updated_function() but using function_() in FinancialInstruments?

Comment: I suggest you to use standard Javascript _camelCase_  instead of _name_of_things_ . Specially, I discourage to use _name_of_thing__ . All of this confuses a lot and discourages anyone to help you.